# How do you use の as a de-facto が particle?

Tags: particle-の, particle-が

Apparently の can be used as a de-facto が particle. Now this sorta makes sense as in Japanese the line between something defining scope (A は/が B), and some defining association (A の B), is vary thin.

That said, could someone explain to me when exactly you can use の in place of が, like it explains on [Jisho.org](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AE), as I'm far to curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

の and が are interchangeable at least in the following two cases:

- In a relative clause, の works as a subject marker just like が. This is fairly common and we hear this every day. See: [How does the の work in 「日本人の知らない日本語」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/5010)
- In archaic Japanese, が worked like の that describes possession/belonging. There are still some fixed expressions and place names (such as [鬼が島](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momotar%C5%8D)) that still use が for this purpose. You may hear が used in this way in samurai dramas, too. You should not freely construct a phrase using this が. See: [「が」vs「の」 with possessives](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39264/5010)

Comment: In the second case, can/does the が become a ヶ?  For example, is 関ヶ原 an instance of this?

Comment: In proper mouns, yes I think so. 鬼が島 is also commonly written as 鬼ヶ島. Of course no one uses 我ヶ家 or such.