# Do I need to use の or が in this sentence

Tags: grammar

先生の言ったとおりにやってください
or
先生が言ったとおりにやってください

I'm trying to say "Please do as the teacher said"

Answer (score 3):

In relative clauses, が and の are *mostly* interchangeable. These two sentences are equally correct, and sound almost identical to me.

See: [How does the の work in 「日本人の知らない日本語」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/5010)

Comment: am I still allowed to use が in 本のとおりに炊いた [cook by the book] ?

Comment: @user22630 No, that の is not the subject marker. It's the particle that connects two *nouns*, and such の is not interchangeable with が (except in [rare situations related to archaic Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/43570/5010)).