# Do possessive pronouns exist at all in Japanese or the only way to refer to possession is through the "no" particle?

Tags: particle-の, possession

In English or Spanish there are possessive pronouns like my, your, her, his, mi, tu, su, etc. that you can use to show possession. For example, my car. But in Japanese the only way I've seen (or that I remember right now) for a phrase like that is with the use of the particle "no". 私の車. Is that the only way there is?

Comment: Japanese isn't Indo-European. Why would you expect possessive pronouns?

Comment: I dont know what to expect in a non- indo-European language. There are many similarities and differences between Indo-European and non Indo-European languages, besides that, I've just been told there is a possesive pronoun for "I" in japanese, was that wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

我【わ】が is almost recognized in modern Japanese as a fixed single word that means *my*. が was a possession marker like の in old Japanese, but this meaning has dropped out of use. Modern dictionaries usually list this as [a distinct entry](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/237540/meaning/m0u/%E6%88%91%E3%81%8C/) (as a [連体詞](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1016/5010)). 我らが is similar.

- [「が」vs「の」 with possessives](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39264/5010)

Besides these, I don't think there are common possessive personal pronouns.

Comment: so there is a possesive pronoun only for "I" but not for you, he, she , they, etc? That sounds kinda unusual in a language, doesnt it? or am I missunderstanding and you are only answering the possesive pronoun of "I" since my question might not be the most clear one?

Comment: 我が is not a regular possessive pronoun but an exceptional expression that happened to survive to this day, and it's etymologically obviously two words. We call it a "word" today because it no longer follows the modern Japanese grammar pattern. Every language has some tricky expressions derived from its old form.