# Difference among んがため and べく?

Tags: grammar

could somebody help me understanding the difference between んがため and べく? They both mean "In order to", but I don't think they are interchangeable. Could somebody provide me some examples to understand the difference?

Comment: Can you give us the full sentences? That first one doesn't seem right.

Comment: A nice explanation of 「～んがため（に）」 here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLKht3bZ1lo&t  Watch the first half.

Answer (score 1):

べく is stiff and literary. んがため is even more literary and often theatrical. This ん is an archaic volitional auxiliary, and が is an archaic possessive particle explained [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39264/5010). Grammatically (ん)がため works like のため. See also: [Is there a difference between んがため and ために?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5396/5010)

Answer (score 0):

せんがため is a dated and an emphatic expression that should be rather taken as "just because", unlike すべく. That's the difference.