# meaning of ~に於るが如く

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of the structure ~に於るが如くin the sentence「兵士の気節に於るが如く」?

It is my understanding that [Verb]+が如く is a somewhat literary synonym for [Verb]+ように, meaning "like [Verb]", or "in the manner of [Verb]" and [Noun]+に於る means "regarding [Noun]", or "as for [Noun]", but I'm not sure how the two articulate.

Could it be that が如く instead complements the noun phrase 兵士の気節に於る, all together meaning something like "Like the moral backbone of the soldier"?

Comment: I guess almost all Japanese people dont understand the phrase you cited especially without context. におけるがごとく looks quite strange collocation, though perhaps our ancestors would say so hundreds years ago or so.

Comment: It's relatively easy to translate 兵士の気節が如く without context, but 兵士の気節**に於る**が如く is hard to interpret without the full context. From what I could google, this phrase is originally from [this book](https://dl.ndl.go.jp/info:ndljp/pid/1080981) written in 1970, but I could not identify the exact page. Please share the surrounding context. And could you tell us how much do you know about classical Japanese?

Comment: For context: the phrase appears here https://kotobank.jp/word/気節-474038 in the example sentences for the word 気節. This example comes from a book written in the 1870's so it is indeed quite old. After some quick googling I found that the phrase also appears here https://hiroseki.sakura.ne.jp/minpon.html in the sentence 然し民主主義といへば，社会民主党などといふ場合に於けるが如く，「国家の主権は人民にあり」といふ学説と混同され易い。in an equally old text.

Comment: @naruto Sorry I did not see your comment before posting mine, I encountered the phrase as I was looking for the definition of 気節 in kotobank. I thought that its meaning would be somewhat self-contained given that it was used as an example sentence. I do not know much about classical Japanese.

Comment: Okay, so no one of us don't know the full context :) That's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

兵士の気節に於るが如く means not "like the moral backbone of soldiers" but "like **in** the moral backbone of soldiers" or "similarly to **the case of** the moral backbone of soldiers". (気骨 is a fairly rare word and I don't know if 'moral backbone' is the best translation, but let's leave it for now.)

- が如く is roughly the same as の如く, and they mean "like ～" or "similarly to ～". が was a possession marker in classical Japanese. It follows a noun.

  - [Why is there a が in 深淵に臨むが如し?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/70684/5010)
  - [「が」vs「の」 with possessives](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39264/5010)
- 於る【おける】 is a perfective attributive form of 於く【おく】 in classical Japanese, but you probably know this [as a fixed grammar pattern](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6-ni-oite-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B-ni-okeru-meaning/). For now, please know that attributive form of a classical verb worked as a noun, and this pattern sometimes appears in modern Japanese, too. So here 兵士の気節に於る is a *noun* phrase meaning "the case/situation of the moral backbone of soldiers".

  - [How can （の）目指すは be grammatical?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12538/5010)
  - [<動詞の辞書形>　+　がよい ―　How is this allowed?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6714/5010)

Likewise, 社会民主党などといふ場合に於けるが如く in the example you found means "as seen in the case where people say something like 社会民主党".

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough explanation! Would ~に於るのように work as an equivalent, less archaic version?

Comment: @grove No, when you say this using modern grammar, ～におけるように is enough. Don't use the nominalizer.