# Is 'Kimi ga yo' a valid japanese predicate?

Tags: grammar

I'm currently learning Japanese and struggling at understanding the translation of the japanese anthem 'Kimi ga yo' supposedly translated as 'Your reign'. I heard about double subject construct so I initially thought it would be the case but as the sentence is followed by 'wa', I couldn't understand how it would be a complete valid sentence by its own since yo is not a verb but a noun and the subject particle 'ga' need a verb to apply to. Why the sentence is not 'Kimi no yo' ? (possessive particle).

Thanks

Comment: が can be possessive [「が」vs「の」 with possessives](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/39265)

Comment: So indeed in this case が is not the subject marker but a possessive marker. I didn't know about that possibility. Thank you